# Matrices with $M\binom ab\not<\binom 11$

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, inequality, linear-transformations

Let $Q:=\{(x,y)\colon\max\{x,y\}<1\}$ and
$Q_0:=\{(x,y)\colon\max\{x,y\}\le1\}$. Also, let $\Gamma:=\mathbb N^2$.

Is there any comprehensible description of the set of all real square matrices $M$ of order $2$ such that $M\binom{1}{0}\in Q_0$, $M\binom{0}{1}\in Q_0$, and $M\Gamma$ is disjoint from $Q$, with the possible exception of the vector $M\binom{1}{1}$ which can be in $Q$?

As an example, $M$ has this property given that each of the two column sums of $M$ is $2/3$ at least. Another example:
 $$ M=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ -1/2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}. $$
In contrast, if all elements of $M$ are non-positive, then $M$ does not have the property in question.

Comment: By (1), do you mean value or sum?

Comment: @Alex: Sorry, I am afraid I don't get it. The matrix $M$ must satisfy two conditions; condition (1) says that each of the four elements of $M$ is smaller than or equal to $1$.

Comment: OK so it's the value of the elements.

Comment: Can I confirm my understanding?  The desired property is: (1) each entry of $M$ is $\le 1$, and (2) $M {a \choose b} \notin Q$ for integers $a, b \ge 1, a+b \ge 3$.  And you would like a "comprehensible description" of the set of such $M$ with this desired property.  Am I right?

Comment: @antkam: Absolutely.

Answer (score 2):

I think something analogous to your [conjecture in your other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3675115/intersection-of-two-angles-in-mathbb-r2) is correct.

For simplicity let:

- $\mathbb{N} = \{1, 2, 3, \dots\}$ and $\mathbb{N}_0 = \{0, 1, 2, 3, \dots\}$
- $A = \{ [0, 1]^T, [1, 0]^T \}, B = \{[1, 2]^T, [2 ,1]^T, [2, 2]^T\}, C = \{[p, q]^T \in \mathbb{N}^2 : p + q \ge 3\}$

> Claim: Consider $M \in \mathbb{R}_{2 \times 2}$.  We have:
>
> $$ (\forall v \in A: M v \in Q_0) \cap (\forall v \in B: M v \notin Q) \implies \forall v \in C: Mv \notin Q$$

In other words, to check if $M$ has the desired property all you need to check are the five points in $A$ and $B$.  IMHO this qualifies as a "comprehensible description" but that's for you to judge.  :)

Proof:

Suppose $M$ is invertible, i.e. its two columns are linearly independent.  We will interpret a column vector as a point in $(x,y)$ plane.  The points $\{ Mv : v \in  \mathbb{N}_0^2\}$ form a grid on the plane; to be more specific, it forms a quadrant of an infinite grid.  We are interested in $M$ s.t. the points $MA$ all $ \in Q_0$ and the points $MC$ all $\notin Q$.

The problem becomes much easier to visualize if we transform the plane and use the columns of $M$ as basis.  In this transformed space, the grid points are the integral lattice points $\mathbb{N}_0^2$ and now $Q$ and $Q_0$ are transformed to some other shape.  But what are these shapes?  The constraint $x \le 1$ transforms into a half-plane not through the origin, and same for the constraint $y \le 1$.  Thus $Q$ and $Q_0$ (the transformed versions) can be characterized by drawing two arbitrary intersecting lines, neither through the origin, and then picking one of the four quadrants.  $Q$ is the interior of the chosen quadrant and $Q_0$ includes the boundary.  The important thing (indeed the *only* important thing) is that the transformed $Q, Q_0$ are *convex*.

The claim is now geometrically intuitive.  The points are as follows:

```
y-axis
7 . C C C C C C C
6 . C C C C C C C
5 . C C C C C C C
4 . C C C C C C C
3 . C C C C C C C
2 . B B C C C C C
1 A . B C C C C C
0 . A . . . . . .
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 x-axis
```

Since the two points $A \in Q_0$, if any of the points  $C \in Q$ then the triangle formed by these three points must include one of the $B$ points, and since $C$ is in the interior $Q$, the included $B$ is also in the interior $Q$, which is a contradiction.

(To be more clear: for any $C$ along the main diagonal $(x=y)$ the triangle would include $[2, 2]^T$, and for any $C$ above the main diagonal $(y > x)$ the triangle would include $[1, 2]$.)

Finally we are left with the case where the two columns of $M$ are linearly dependent.  I actually have a bit of trouble with this case algebraically, but geometrically the transformed space is basically collapsed into one dimension and $Q$ is just a semi-infinite interval, so it all "should" work...  Sorry, will think more about this degenerate case when I have more time.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It sounds to me like a (partially incomplete) solution to the follow-up problem, but not quite as a complete solution to the present one. Still lacking are the treatment of the five conditions corresponding to the points A and B, and a solution of the case where $M$ is degenerate; also, it would be good to have a formal, algebraic argument for the two paragraphs following the diagram.

Comment: agree that the degenerate case is not handled yet and also agree the "pictorial" argument is not formal.  but what do you mean by "lacking the treatment of the five conditions corr. to the points A and B"?  i am basically saying $M$ has the desired condition iff it satisfies those five conditions.  there is not much point in expanding those five conditions into equations about $M_{ij}$, right?

Comment: Well, I eventually plan to "apply" this in some problem; so, yes, there is a solid point in simplifying and understanding these conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I have so far; it's not complete and I don't think I will complete it.

Denote by $A$ the set of matrices satisfying your conditions, and $Z:=\{(a,b)\mid a\geq 1,b\geq1,(a,b)\neq(1,1)\}$. For $M$ a matrix, we will denote the coefficients by
$$\begin{pmatrix}
m_{11} & m_{12} \\ m_{21} & m_{22}
\end{pmatrix}$$
Let $J$ be the matrix of all $1$'s.

If $M\in A$ and $M<M'$ ($m'_ij>m_ij$ for all $i,j$), then $M'\in A$. This is because we test $M'$ on positive vectors. Moreover, $A$ is stable by permutation of rows and/or columns.

It suffices to find $M\in A$ such that there exists $(a_0,b_0)\in Z$ such that $m_{11}a_0+m_{12}b_0=1$. Indeed, denoting this subset by $A'$, we have $A=A'+\Bbb R_+J$ (the main argument is that $A$ is stable by $\Bbb R_+J$).

Let $M\in A'$. Then there exists $(a_0,b_0)\in Z$ such that $m_{11}a_0+m_{12}b_0=1$, so there exists $t\in\Bbb R$ such that $m_{11}=t\frac1{a_0}$ and $m_{12}=(1-t)\frac1{b_0}$. Reciprocally, if $M\in A$ such that $m_{11}$ and $m_{12}$ have this form then $M\in A'$.

Let $M$ be a matrix with $m_{11}$ and $m_{12}$ of the previous form. Then $M\in A$ iff $M\in A'$ iff
$$\forall (a,b)\in Z,\quad t\frac a{a_0}+(1-t)\frac{b}{b_0}<1\Rightarrow m_{21}a+m_{22}b\geq 1.$$
Repeating the previous reasoning, it suffices to find the matrices $M\in A$ of the form
$$\begin{bmatrix}
t\frac1{a_0} & (1-t)\frac1{b_0} \\
u\frac1{a_1} & (1-u)\frac1{b_1}
\end{bmatrix}$$
where $t\frac{a_1}{a_0}+(1-t)\frac{b_1}{b_0}<1$. The "only" thing left to check is that $u$ satisfies
$$\forall (a,b)\in Z,\quad t\frac a{a_0}+(1-t)\frac{b}{b_0}<1\Rightarrow u\frac{a}{a_1}+(1-u)\frac{b}{b_1}\geq1.\tag{$*$}$$
The reason I put quotes around "only" is because this is where I got stuck. If we can get some necessary and sufficient condition on $u$ for it to satisfy $(*)$, say $\mathcal P_{a_0,b_0,t,a_1,b_1}(u)$, then we can write
$$A=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}
t\frac1{a_0} & (1-t)\frac1{b_0} \\
u\frac1{a_1} & (1-u)\frac1{b_1}
\end{bmatrix}\left|\begin{array}{l}(a_0,b_0)\in Z,t\in\Bbb R, \\
(a_1,b_1)\in Z,t\frac{a_1}{a_0}+(1-t)\frac{b_1}{b_0}<1\\
u\in\Bbb R,\mathcal P_{a_0,b_0,t,a_1,b_1}(u)\end{array}\right.\right\}+\Bbb R_+J.$$
My conclusion: either we can calculate this property, and we get a messy characterization of $A$, or there's a simpler strategy I didn't see.

Comment: Thank you for the answer; I have to check it yet...