# Intersection of two angles in $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, inequality, linear-transformations

Related to [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3672932/181098).

Let $M$ be a square matrix of order $2$ with all elements not exceeding $1$, and let $Q=\big\{\binom xy\colon \max\{x,y\}<1\big\}$. Given that $M\binom 11\in Q$, while $M\binom 12,M\binom 21,M\binom 22\notin Q$, does it follow that, indeed, $M\binom ab\notin Q$ for any vector $\binom ab$ with positive integer coordinates other than the vector $\binom ab=\binom 11$?